# Square made using conic-gradient() is not showing up in Firefox but working fine in Chrome. What is the workaround?

Tags: html, css, firefox

Try to run the below code in Chrome and Firefox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        div {
            height: 60px;
            width:60px;
            background: conic-gradient(
                #ffde15 0% 12.5%,
                #27abfd 12.5% 37.5%,
                #eb1c22 37.5% 62.5%,
                #06a049 62.5% 87.6%,
                #ffde15 87.6% 100%
            );
        }
    </style>

    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In Chrome, it works fine and produces result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUSke.png), but it does not show up in Firefox.

In Firefox, we can visit `about:config` and enable `layout.css.conic-gradient.enabled`, but I need a proper workaround.

Please can you help me draw the square which works in both Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Well, according to [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-conic-gradients), `conic-gradient` does not work on early versions of firefox *(v82- which is the current stable version of firefox)*.

Comment: Yes, that's true! Then how can I draw it so that it works in both Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for using `conic-gradient`?

Comment: No, there is no requirement of using `conic-gradient`. But I don't know what other options can be used. It is perfectly fine if I use `linear-gradient` or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only intend to create such a colourized triangles within a square. You can modify the border property of an existing square and then colourize it with your desired colours. Which is provide cross-browser support for you.

So your final code should be something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
  div {
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    border: 30px solid;
    border-top-color: #ffde15;
    border-left-color: #06a049;
    border-right-color: #27abfd;
    border-bottom-color: #eb1c22;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**NOTE:** If you want to know how it exactly works [this article](https://dev.to/mightytechno/create-a-triangle-shape-using-css-1coi) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

linear-gradient can do the job here with `clip-path`

```css
.box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #27abfd 50%, #ffde15 0);
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #eb1c22 50%, #06a049 0);
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,100% 0,0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Another solution with rotation:

```css
.box {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 141.42%; /* 100% * sqrt(2) */
  width:141.42%;
  margin:-20.52% 0 0 -20.52%; /* 50% * (sqrt(2) - 1)*/
  background: 
    linear-gradient(#eb1c22 50%, #06a049 0) left,
    linear-gradient(#27abfd 50%, #ffde15 0) right;
  background-size:50% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```